# $ npm install npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\LeadMgt_Use.This.One\package.json'

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to this world and don't understand majority of the terms/answers I found in this website.

I was informed this is the place where you can get help.

I am using a work computer and so I only have access to the C drive.

If anyone has a step by step instruction please advise. Steps I've already taken was to open the folder that contains the file and package.json and right click inside the folder and click no "Git Bash Here" Once GitBash opens I input the command "Install NPM" and receive the error message. Please help as I've been attempting to get this resolved over week. Thank you so much for your time.

**Desired Solution** Ability to Successfully input command "NPM INSTALL" into GITBASH

**Current Issue**

```
$ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\LeadMgt_Use.This.One\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\LeadMgt_Use.This.One\package.json'
npm WARN LeadMgt_Use.This.One No description
npm WARN LeadMgt_Use.This.One No repository field.
npm WARN LeadMgt_Use.This.One No README data
npm WARN LeadMgt_Use.This.One No license field.
```